# how does neo4j indexing work behind the scenes?

Tags: neo4j

I am currently playing around with neo4j and have was curious how neo4j indexing works behind the scenes. While I have seen that indexed queries are orders of magnitude faster, I was wondering what the overhead of adding indexes are, and how they work internally

Answer (score 1):

Indexing is only used for looking up start-nodes in your queries, it is not used to speed up the graph-traversal itself.

Neo4j uses a wrapper around index-providers, which allows addition and querying of tuples of: label,prop,value->node-id. Default index provider is Apache Lucene but you can implement your own too, see: https://github.com/jexp/neo4j-mapdb-index